# How to get m3u8 playlist from yotube video link?

Tags: javascript, youtube, google-chrome-devtools, youtube-dl, m3u8

In the past, I was able to get m3u8 playlist links using Chrome developer tools while checking network tab.

I've tried to get it today, but I wasn't able to find it. I've spent almost whole day trying to find it. I've read many articles but without any luck.

[image]

This is not working anymore. It doesn't show anything. But as youtube-dl is still working, I am positive about it can be done somehow but hidden somewhere.

Anyone dealt with this recently?

Answer (score 1):

I've got same issue for about a month. I think it is hidden as base64 encoding under a response.

Comment: Have you able to find which response is it?

Comment: I see encoded responses but couldn't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a combination of youtube's private api and web scraping to get it.